# WordPress site giving the following error: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(). Convert?

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is that, after adding a new plugin to my Wordpress CMS, my site as well as the Wordpress CMS shows a PHP error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/a4921378/public_html/wp-content/themes/xscholar/framework/includes/core-functions.php on line 433 and defined in /home/a4921378/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1285

**Image:**

[image: Error Image]

Can someone please tell me what is wrong and I would be very appreciative if someone converts/fixes this piece of code.

**Me:**
I'm an amateur coder, only understand the basics and haven't learned PHP yet, I use Wordpress quite often but something like this never came up before. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong but haven't succeeded in 2 hours.

I have already visited the pages [php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/) and [missing-argument-2-for-wpdbprepare](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213584/missing-argument-2-for-wpdbprepare)

```
$terms = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT name, slug FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'terms, ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy WHERE ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'terms.term_id = ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy.term_id AND taxonomy = "product_cat" ORDER BY name ASC;'));
$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT wposts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '%s' AND wposts.post_type = 'attachment'", $attachment_url));
```

Comment: You should not have to deal with this yourself - contact the author of the plugin or find a different plugin that does the same thing. You don't want to put yourself in a situation where you're making changes to a plugin when you don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `$wpdb->prepare` for your first query, because the query does not have any placeholder ([What a placeholder is?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders)). Just simply use:

```
$terms = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT name, slug FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'terms, ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy WHERE ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'terms.term_id = ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy.term_id AND taxonomy = "product_cat" ORDER BY name ASC;');
```

Your second query has a placeholder (that `%s`), but it is wrapped in quotes. It should not be wrapped, the `prepare` method takes care of it. Just use:

```
$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT wposts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = %s AND wposts.post_type = 'attachment'", $attachment_url));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Actually, this code is written by the developer of the theme, i don't know php.

Comment: If I copy the code you corrected as it is and paste it in place of the original one, will it get the job done without errors?

Comment: I did not test it, you will have to try it :) Most probably it will work.

Comment: Probably the theme was developed for WordPress older than version 3.5, when the `prepare` method did not expect 2 mandatory arguments.

Comment: Yes. It is an old theme from what I concluded after looking it up on google and not too popular either.

Comment: Thank you so very much. IT WORKS. :)